# Preserve line-breaks when running .text() on divs - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have some html content in a div, which I copied from somewhere. 
now when I use -:

```
var text = $("div#myDiv").text()
```

It removes all the line-breaks and any other tabs or spaces. How can I preserve them.

Comment: `.text()` already does that. http://jsfiddle.net/552jT/

Comment: @KevinB Seems to work inside textarea but not divs. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/synva/

Comment: @kdev well of course, those aren't linebreaks. those are break tags, completely different.

Comment: @KevinB, sorry, yes of course. That's the problem that I'm trying to solve...

Answer (score 0):

When you need to do that use .html() instead of .text()

Comment: But if i user html(), it also returns any other html tags associated. I don't want them, i need only the textual formatting(tabs, spaces and line breaks) to be preserved

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to preserve lines:

```
var item = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var text = item.innerText || item.textContent;
```